# eth.getCode() always returns "0x"

Tags: go-ethereum

I want to distinguish between contract addresses and smart contract addresses. But when running

```
web3.eth.getCode()
```

in the geth console with either a contract or a non-contract address, it returns "0x".

I am using geth 1.8.22. Does anyone has an idea why that happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met this problem sometime ago, in my case the node I connected to isn't fully synced, that is to say, the node is in the midst of a fast sync, you should know that

```
Fast sync finishes syncing Blocks/Transactions/Receipts well before 
the state sync finished and the contract code is part of the state sync.
```

Comment: It is possible to check whether node is synced or not via `web3.eth.syncing`.